# Git: cannot remove a directory from the staging area

Tags: git

Every time I do:

```
git push
```

I get this error

> remote: error: File bin/downward is 162.88 MB; this exceeds GitHub's
> file size limit of 100.00 MB

Nevertheless, I have done

```
git rm --cached -r bin
```

and also:

```
git reset
```

and I also put this in the .gitignore:

```
/bin/
```

So, I don't understand why it's still trying to push this "bin" directory.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: if the file is present in you HEAD commit, you have to remove it from there : `git commit --amend`. If the file is also present in previous commits, you have to edit your history to prune it from your history.

Comment: This reads to me like using `git reset` means you have reverted the `git rm` with that. After the `git rm` call what does `git status` say? Doesn't it also need a commit which removes the files first and then push that?